# Previous URL not being removed from actual one

Tags: html, django

I'm not familiar with HTML and I've got the following problem. I've got this button code in which I'm referencing another HTML with a parameter.

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" href="reto_resultado/{{ clave_primaria }}">Comprobar</a>
```

The problem comes when I go to another page of my site clicking in a button in the navbar. I get this URL in the browser:

```
http://localhost:8000/reto_resultado/reto.html
```

Why doesn't 'reto_resultado' just disappear from the URL, as it has nothing to do with the page I just went to?

This is the button that should reference http://localhost:8000/reto.html

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" href="reto.html">Siguiente pregunta</a>
```

Comment: Because your `href="..."` *contains* it: `href="reto_resultado/{{ clave_primaria }}"`...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem No, when clicking in the button it generates the following URL: http://localhost:8000/reto_resultado/1 which is OK for me. The problem is that when I click on a button to go to index page, reto_resultado is still in the URL: http://localhost:8000/reto_resultado/inicio.html, which makes nonsense

Comment: Well we can not know that here, since you do not provide any context what `{{ clave_primaria }}` is.

Comment: It is just the primary key Django generates for a Question object. In my last comment, that would be '1'

Comment: Can you post the code for the `<a>` that is supposed to link to `localhost:8000/reto.html`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you do not put a slash at the beginning of the `href`, the path is treated as a relative path. This means that the contents of the `href` are appended to the current location.

For example, if the current location is `example.com/foo` and you click on the element `<a href="bar">bar</a>` you will be routed to `example.com/foo/bar`.

If, in the previous example, you wanted to go from `example.com/foo` to `example.com/bar`, you can put a leading slash in the `href` attribute so that it is treated as an absolute path.

In your case, you should have an element that looks something like this:

```
<a href="/reto.html">Siguiente pregunta</a>
```

Which, regardless of the current location, will route to `example.com/reto.html`